# Attribute access on a decorated callable class

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, exponential-backoff

I have a callable class:

```
class CallMeMaybe:

    __name__ = 'maybe'

    def __init__(self):
        self.n_calls = 0

    def __call__(self):
        self.n_calls += 1
        raise Exception
```

That seems to work as advertised:

```
>>> f = CallMeMaybe()
>>> f.n_calls
0
>>> for i in range(7):
...     try:
...         f()
...     except Exception:
...         pass
...     
>>> f.n_calls
7
```

I want to decorate it with an exponential [backoff](https://pypi.org/project/backoff/):

```
from backoff import on_exception, expo
dec = on_exception(expo, Exception, max_tries=3, on_backoff=print)
f = CallMeMaybe()
f2 = dec(f)
```

Now it looks like attribute access stopped working:

```
>>> f2.n_calls
0
>>> f2()
{'target': <__main__.CallMeMaybe object at 0xcafef00d>, 'args': (), 'kwargs': {}, 'tries': 1, 'elapsed': 2.1e-05, 'wait': 0.4843249208229148}
{'target': <__main__.CallMeMaybe object at 0xcafef00d>, 'args': (), 'kwargs': {}, 'tries': 2, 'elapsed': 0.484935, 'wait': 1.6524016553598126}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
... blah blah blah
>>> f2.n_calls
0
```

My question: who copied `n_calls` name into `f2`'s namespace, and why?  Now it holds a stale value - the correct value should be 3:

```
>>> f2.__wrapped__.n_calls
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `backoff` module in its implementation [uses `functools.wraps`](https://github.com/litl/backoff/blob/master/backoff/_sync.py#L83) which calls `functools.update_wrapper` and you can see [from the source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/functools.py#l43) that by default it updates the `__dict__` of the wrapper:

```
WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS = ('__module__', '__name__', '__qualname__', '__doc__',
                       '__annotations__')
WRAPPER_UPDATES = ('__dict__',)
def update_wrapper(wrapper,
                   wrapped,
                   assigned = WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS,
                   updated = WRAPPER_UPDATES):
    """Update a wrapper function to look like the wrapped function

       wrapper is the function to be updated
       wrapped is the original function
       assigned is a tuple naming the attributes assigned directly
       from the wrapped function to the wrapper function (defaults to
       functools.WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS)
       updated is a tuple naming the attributes of the wrapper that
       are updated with the corresponding attribute from the wrapped
       function (defaults to functools.WRAPPER_UPDATES)
    """
    for attr in assigned:
        try:
            value = getattr(wrapped, attr)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        else:
            setattr(wrapper, attr, value)
    for attr in updated:
        getattr(wrapper, attr).update(getattr(wrapped, attr, {}))
    +
−# Issue #17482: set __wrapped__ last so we don't inadvertently copy it
    # from the wrapped function when updating __dict__
    wrapper.__wrapped__ = wrapped
    # Return the wrapper so this can be used as a decorator via partial()
    return wrapper

def wraps(wrapped,
          assigned = WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS,
          updated = WRAPPER_UPDATES):
    """Decorator factory to apply update_wrapper() to a wrapper function

       Returns a decorator that invokes update_wrapper() with the decorated
       function as the wrapper argument and the arguments to wraps() as the
       remaining arguments. Default arguments are as for update_wrapper().
       This is a convenience function to simplify applying partial() to
       update_wrapper().
    """
    return partial(update_wrapper, wrapped=wrapped,
                   assigned=assigned, updated=updated)
```

---

Unfortunately it seems impossible to achieve what you want. The `backoff` module could allow optional `assigned`/`updated` attributes lists to be passed to `wraps` to avoid the copy of the attribute. However this would really solve the issue because at that point you would not have access to `n_calls`.

You probably need to use a mutable object instead of a plain `int`.